# decorator inside class & decorated classmethod without 'self' gives strange results

Tags: python, class, decorator

Example code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from functools import wraps

class MyClass(object):
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  #decorator inside class
  def call(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args):
      print 'Wrapper: ', args
    return wrapper

  #decorated 'method' without self
  @call
  def myfunc(a): 
    pass

c = MyClass()
c.myfunc(1)
```

Returns:

```
Wrapper:  (<test3.MyClass object at 0xb788a34c>, 1)
```

Is this normal? Can someone explain?

If this is a *feature* I would use it in my library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly normal.

The function `myfunc` is replacecd by an instance of `wrapper`. The signature of `wrapper` is `(*args)`. because it is a bound method, the first argument is the instance of `MyClass` which is printed out after the string `Wrapper: '.

What's confusing you?

It's worth noting that if you use `call` as a decorator from *outside* of `MyClass`, it will generate a `TypeError`. One way around this is to apply the `staticmethod` decorator to it but then you can't call it during class construction.

It's a little bit hacky but I address how to have it both ways [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421337/accessing-a-decorator-in-a-parent-class-from-the-child-in-python/3422823#3422823).

**update after comment**

it gets the instance as the first argument regardless of if you type `self` in the parameter list because *after* the class is created, and an instance instantiated, it is a *bound method*. when you call it in the form

```
@instance.call
def foo(bar):
    return bar + 1
```

it expands to

```
def foo(bar):
    return bar + 1
foo = instance.call(f)
```

but note that you are calling it on an instance! This will **automatically** expand to a call of the form

```
def foo(bar):
    return bar + 1
foo = MyClass.call(instance, f)
```

This is how methods work. But you only defined `call` to take one argument so this raises a `TypeError`.

As for calling it *during* class construction, it works fine. but the function that it returns gets passed an instance of `MyClass` when *it* is called for the same reason that I explained above. Specifically, whatever arguments you explicity pass to it come *after* the implicit and automatic placement of the instance that it is called upon at the front of the argument list.

Comment: I didn't specify 'self' in myfunc, but the decorator got the 'self' value at call. If I put the decorator out of the class, it fails (what is perfectly normal:).

Comment: but maybe you are right, and it's expected. I'll check the code of 'wraps'.

Comment: @bencevoltam `wraps` has nothing to do with this! see my updates.

Answer (score 1):

```
@call
def myfunc(a):
    ...
```

is equivalent to

```
def myfunc(a):
    ...
myfunc=call(myfunc)
```

The orginial `myfunc` may have expected only one argument, `a`, but after being decorated with `call`, the new `myfunc` can take any number of positional arguments, and they will all be put in `args`.

Notice also that

```
def call(f)
```

never calls `f`. So the fact that

```
def myfunc(a)
```

lacks the normal self argument is not an issue. It just never comes up.

When you call `c.myfunc(1)`,  `wrapper(*args)` gets called.

What is args? Well, since `c.myfunc` is a method call, `c` is sent as the first argument, followed by any subsequent arguments. In this case, the subsequent argument is 1. Both arguments are sent to `wrapper`, so `args` is the 2-tuple `(c,1)`.

Thus, you get

```
Wrapper:  (<test3.MyClass object at 0xb788a34c>, 1)
```