# How to implement instance-dependent functionality using parent class decorator?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I would like to implement a parent class decorator in my child class whose functionality depends on the state of the child class instance. I've tried coming at this problem from three different angles, none of which have worked:

---

#### [Parent *method*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3422823)

If `give_feedback` is a static method, there's no `self` within the method. But if it's an instance method, there's no `self` within the namespace in which it's applied.

```
class Interface:
    def __init__(self, quiet=False):
        self.quiet = quiet

    def echo(self, text):
        if not self.quiet:
            print(text)

    def give_feedback(self, func):
        def wrapper(*args):
            print('Calling give_feedback.')
            self.echo(func(*args))
        return wrapper

class App(Interface):
    @Interface.give_feedback  # self not defined here.
    def app_func(self, num):
        feedback = 'Success with {num}'.format(num=num)
        return feedback

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = App()
    a.app_func(3)
```

---

#### [Parent *class* using __call__](https://krzysztofzuraw.com/blog/2016/python-class-decorators.html) (cf. link example_1)

Can't access the object from within `__call__`.

```
class Interface:
    # ...

    class give_feedback:
        def __init__(self, func):
            self.func = func

        def __call__(self, *args):
            print(
                'Calling {func}'.format(func=self.func)
            )
            instance = get_obj_instance(self.func)  # What is this?
            return instance.echo(self.func(instance, *args))

class App(Interface):
    # ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # ...
```

---

#### [Parent *descriptor*](https://krzysztofzuraw.com/blog/2016/python-class-decorators.html) (cf. link example_2)

Can access the object, but no arguments.

```
class Interface:
    # ...

    class give_feedback:
        # ...

        def __get__(self, instance, owner):
            print(
                'Getting {func} from {inst} of {ownr}'.format(
                    func=self.func, inst=instance, ownr=owner
                )
            )
            num = 2  # How to get num???
            return instance.echo(self.func(instance, num))

class App(Interface):
    # ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = App()
    a.app_func  # No ability to pass parameters.
```

---

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not combine the 2nd and 3rd methods? Use `__get__` to get the class instance, and `__call__` to decorate with `echo`. Rather than returning `app_func`, return a new object that holds the instance and has the desired `__call__` behavior.

```
class Interface:
    def __init__(self, quiet=False):
        self.quiet = quiet

    def echo(self, text):
        if not self.quiet:
            print(text)

    class give_feedback:
        def __init__(self, func):
            self.func = func

        def __get__(self, instance, owner):
            return self.InstHolder(instance, self.func)

        class InstHolder:
            def __init__(self, inst, func):
                self.inst = inst
                self.func = func

            def __call__(self, *args):
                return self.inst.echo(self.func(self.inst, *args))


class App(Interface):
    @Interface.give_feedback
    def app_func(self, num):
        feedback = 'Success with {num}'.format(num=num)
        return feedback


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = App()
    a.app_func(3)
    a.quiet = True
    a.app_func(4)
```